# How to convert bytes into strings for entries in a dataframe (Python)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, byte

My dataframe looks like the below. What is the quickest way to convert each entry into regular strings and floats? I'm thinking about converting the dataframe to a dictionary first and applying `.decode()` to each column one element by element.

[image: dataframe]

Comment: Where did the data come from, exactly? It's likely that the best solution is to fix the code that created the Dataframe in the first place.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I feel the same. Unfortunately I have no access to the first-hand data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with `decode`

```
df = df.apply(lambda x : x.str.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Brilliant! Exactly what I'd expect. Thank you very much!